# How push a task with SpecId in firebase-queue with nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-queue

In the document example we can see :

```
var Queue = require('firebase-queue'),
    Firebase = require('firebase');

var ref = new Firebase('https://<your-firebase>.firebaseio.com');
var queueRef = ref.child('queue');
var messagesRef = ref.child('messages');

var options = {
  'specId': 'new_user'
};

new Queue(queueRef, options, function(data, progress, resolve, reject) {
  // sanitize input message
  console.log(data.message);

  // pass sanitized message and username along to be fanned out
  resolve(data);
});
```

How save a new task with the specId `new_user`or other custom `specId`

```
var task = {'userId': "0338ba4d-191f-4044-9af0-4c76f47aeef9"};

ref.child("queue").child("tasks").push(task);
```

This push does not trigger the queue.
If I remove the `options` from the Queue, it does work (of course)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

tl;dr the `start_state`for the spec should match the `_state` of the task.

You need push the definition of each spec to the Firebase queue. For e.g.

```
  ref.child('queue/specs').set({
    new_user: {
     start_state: 'add_new_user',
     in_progress_state: 'add_new_user_in_progress'
    }
  });
```

Here `new_user` is the specId that you have specified for the queue. Now when you push a task, you need to set the `_state` to the `start_state` for the spec. For e.g.

```
var task = {'userId': "0338ba4d-191f-4044-9af0-4c76f47aeef9", '_state': 'add_new_user'};
ref.child("queue").child("tasks").push(task);
```

Now this task should be picked up the queue that is created to handled tasks with `specId` `new_user`

Read [this](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-queue#starting-tasks-in-specific-states-optional) and [this](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-queue#creating-jobs-using-custom-specs-and-task-chaining) in the official firebase queue documentation.